# Powershell Script works locally, but not via Remote

Tags: powershell

probably I'm missing some crucial points here:
I'm trying to tinker together a `PowerShell` Script, which stops a Service, copies Data, and then starts the Service again on a different Machine.
Everything working, but with the Default `Get-Service`, like this:

```
Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $serverName | Set-Service -Status Stopped
```

I can't get the Service, be it via IP, full qualified Server Name, or all other names I could think of. So I thought, it would be a good idea to create a small Proxy-Script on the Server, quite simple:

```
param (
    [string]$serviceName,
    [string]$command
)

"Received: " + $serviceName
"Received: " + $command

$serverName = "xx"

if ($command -eq "Stop")
{
    "Stopping Service: " + $serviceName
    Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $serverName | Set-Service -Status Stopped
}

if ($command -eq "Start")
{
    "Starting Service: " + $serviceName
    Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $serverName | Set-Service -Status Running
}
```

This works, if I run this Script on the Server directly, but if I call it via my local Script, via something like:

```
$proxyScriptForServicesPath = $serverRootPath + "HandleWindowsServices.ps1"
$serviceName = $servicePrefix + $folder

$scriptArguments = @()
$scriptArguments += ("-serviceName", $serviceName)
$scriptArguments += ("-command", "stop")

# Stop the Service
Invoke-Expression "$proxyScriptForServicesPath $scriptArguments"
```

I get again the Message, the Service can't be found, even if the values are exactly the same.
I guess I can't outsmart the System that easy, but what am I missing here?

Comment: Is PowerShell Remoting enabled on the remote host?

Comment: Yes, the Service is started. I can also call the ProxyScript, but this doesn't find the WindowsService, if called from a local Script.